# Ember `partial` templating with component

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use a single component in multiple page with different content. for that, I am trying with `partial` templating approach. But I find my way is wrong. any one suggest me the correct way?

name of route : `my-route` and `my-service` both are using same component called `my-component`. my component always having some default info too.. but partially how show different content on different page?

my partials are in template `partials` folder.

here is my try :

```
<h2>This is my Route page</h2>
{{#my-component}}
 <!-- default content should be here -->
{{partial "partials/my-service-partial"}}
{{/my-component}}
```

here is my live demo: [Live Demo in Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a82681e0f38cb1f62f90c1b14cbc16d9?openFiles=templates.partials.my-service-partial.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to render the passed block to a component, you should use `{{ yield }}`, so your component's template should look like:

```html
{{!-- templates/component/my-component.hbs --}}
<div class="parent">
    <h2>Loaded from component default</h2>
    {{ yield }}
</div>
```

You can find some more information in the guides - [Wrapping Content in a Component](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/)

Comment: if you don't mind can you help me by updating my twiddle? I tried yours my content need to sit inside of the parent and as sibling

Comment: You can just move the `yield` block to the position that you want it to appear